# Why does the top half of the span element cover the text and the bottom half does not

Tags: html, css

The following code states my problem.

```css
span {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: 2px solid blue;
  }
p {
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<p>
I am a paragraph and this is a <span>span</span> inside that paragraph. A span is an inline element and so does not respect width and height.
</p>
```

As we can see that the top half of the span element cover the text and the bottom half does not, specifically, the word `'paragraph'` is obscured but `'span is an'` is not

[codepen url here](https://codepen.io/smallnine/pen/MWvgpMJ)

Comment: Because the top part of the text comes before the span, and the bottom half after it.

Comment: So what is your actual question?

Comment: Firstly learn about this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: In the `span` and the `a` tag, actual `height` and `width` don't work.
In your code, only `padding` and `margin` works.
But the actual height of `span` is the `line-height` of its text.
And, in HTML, elements or texts written after are higher in the z-axis.
So `'paragraph'` is below the `span`, and `'span is a'` is above `span`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because of the line by line execution of the file. set `position:relative` for `span` it will be on top of other elements.

```css
span {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  position: relative;
}
p{
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<p>
    I am a paragraph and this is a <span>span</span> inside that paragraph. A span is an inline element and so does not respect width and height.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make the `span` at the top add these two lines to the `span`'s CSS.

```css
span  {
 position: relative;
}
```

```css
span {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  z-index: 999;
  position: relative;
}

p {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  I am a paragraph and this is a <span>span</span> inside that paragraph. A span is an inline element and so does not respect width and height.
</p>
```

And also remember that `width` and `height` doesn't work on inline elements. You can use `inline-block` if you want.

Comment: I think z-index is irrelevant here `position: relative` itself does the job perfectly

Comment: Okay. I'll fix it

Comment: It's Fixed now @Viira